# NumberFormatException: invalid long :""

Tags: java, android

I am getting the NumberFormatException :invalid long "" in runtime.I am posted the relevant code.I mentioned the 40th error line in below coding.

**Stacktrace:**

```
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629): Process: com.android.timesheet, PID: 3629
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.timesheet/com.android.timesheet.ModifyMember}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at java.lang.Long.invalidLong(Long.java:124)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:345)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:318)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at com.android.timesheet.ModifyMember.onCreate(ModifyMember.java:40)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
12-23 04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):     ... 11 more
```

**ModifyMember.java:**

```
public class ModifyMember extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    EditText et;
    Button edit_bt, delete_bt;

    long member_id;

    PersonDatabaseHelper dbcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.modify_member);

        dbcon = new PersonDatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());  
    //  dbcon.open();    

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_mem_id);
        edit_bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_bt_id);
        delete_bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete_bt_id);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        String memberID = i.getStringExtra("memberID");
        String memberName = i.getStringExtra("memberName");

        member_id=Long.parseLong(memberID);  --->40th error line 


        et.setText(memberName);

        edit_bt.setOnClickListener(this);
        delete_bt.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.update_bt_id:
            String memName_upd = et.getText().toString();
            dbcon.updateData(member_id, memName_upd);
            this.returnHome();
            break;

        case R.id.delete_bt_id:

            dbcon.deleteData(member_id);
            this.returnHome();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void returnHome() {

        Intent home_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                NewProjects.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        startActivity(home_intent);
    }

}
```

I didn't know how to resolve this error.Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: sure there is a memberID in your intent?

Comment: Have you debugged and checked the value of memberID? Maybe it's null.

Comment: The `member_id` cannot be cast to a long as it is invalid. It seems like it is blank. Can you debug and check the content of this variable?

Comment: The error is **quite clearly** telling you what's wrong: The thing you're trying to parse is an empty string. What's the question? Why is it empty? We can't answer that, you're the one with the input data, code, and debugger.

Comment: @ChristianDietrich yes.I have a intent

Comment: you r getting empty value in intent for memberID

Comment: i asked if the intent contains the memberID. the error says it is empty. so i think the intent does not contain a value for it

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am understood your point.will find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: ""
memberID could be empty or data in it do not have number
```

> "Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have
>   the appropriate format."

check if your string is empty before you try to convert it (example: check if bundle contains key)

Answer (score 3):

Your logcat clearly said

> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "" 12-23
>   04:30:11.660: E/AndroidRuntime(3629):

Your `memberID` is empty string and you're trying to convert in `Long`.

### Solution:

Check `memberID` is `empty` or not

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(memberID))
{
//Do your job
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`memberId` is an empty string and not a valid long.